Electron builder change msi template
I have an Electron.js project and when I run this command ;
MsiExec /i "Project 1.0.0.msi" HOSTNAME=hostname.org, it doesn't accept the parameter.
I know I need to change the file located at the following path:
C:...\MyProject\node_modules\electron-builder-lib\templates\msi\template.xml.
However, I don't think it's appropriate to change a file in node_modules. So, I created a file named templateRoot.xml in the root directory of the project and I want to specify this file as the MSI configuration in package.json. How can I do this?
i want to change msi template.xml
